# Angular 1.6 - Post request does not show DIV

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I am presenting a problem at the front level when making a request to a webservice REST, with the POST method, by clicking on the button, it is executed successfully, I get the response from the api, the same response must show me a DIV with the message of "successful registration", I made a debug, and in effect the response travels to the point where it should show the message, but it does not, it is as if the view was not built, it is worth noting that if I give two clicks to the button next if the message appears on the front

here my code in the controller

```
 insertFactByCategory.insertFacts(data,$rootScope)
       .success(function(success){
           console.log(success);
           vm.validateMessage(success);
       })
       .error(function(error){
          console.log(error);
       });
```

code in the service factory in angular

```
function insertFacts(data,$rootScope){
    return $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        url: $rootScope.domainUrlHebdoConf+'/semana/insert/category',
        method: "POST",
        data: data
    });
```

I remain attentive to your comments and / or suggestions

Answer (score 0):

It is achievable in multiple ways. One way to achieve this is:

1. Create a div with the success message inside it
2. In the created div add ng-if directive with a scope variable which has the error message. For e.g `<div ng-if="ctrl.message.length>0"> {{ctrl.message}}<\div>`
3. Now, in your controller, whenever you set vm.message = "successful registration", it will show the div. And whenever you set vm.message = ""; it will hide the div

Comment: I´ll try that suggestion